# Canon 5D MK2 battery drain quickly

Tags: canon-5d-mark-ii, battery-drain

the battery on my camera is draining quickly, overnight 15% was drained while the camera was turned off, the lens was taken off, the card was taken out, it has no GPS or anything like that that can cause the drain, and no battery grip.

The firmware is 2.1.2. Freshly installed. I also took out the battery, and also the small battery inside the camera to reset it fully. Every time I charge the batteries to 100% leave it inside to be ready the moment I need it, the camera does not turn on anymore. When I leave the battery out of the camera, and I check the next day, 0% of the battery has drained.

What can cause this?

Comment: How old is this battery? Do you have other battery? Have you try it?

Comment: I have two batteries, and both do the same. They are from 2011, original batteries of the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment these batteries are very old and with high probability they can't keep the charge for long time. This is normal behavior for Li-ion, they have around 500 cycles of charge.

The best recommendation is to buy new batteries and replace existing. Just forget about old batteries and find appropriate way to dispose/recycle them.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the best thing to do is just try it with new batteries.